# Using node js library Socket io without port

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, websocket, socket.io

So i am complete beginner to nodeJs and socket io.Some how i have installed both in my server and made one example `chat application`.

So it works like..if i visit `http://domain.com:3000` everything works fine...But is it possible to just uploade index.html anywhere else For example `http://domain.com/chat/` and insert code like this below in client file.

```
 var connection = new WebSocket('ws://domain.com:3000');
```

My client code

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Chat with socket.io and node.js</title>
    <style>
        #chat{
            height:500px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="chat"></div>
    <form id="send-message">
        <input size="35" id="message"></input>
        <input type="submit"></input>
    </form>

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script>
        jQuery(function($){
            var socket = io.connect();
            var $messageForm = $('#send-message');
            var $messageBox = $('#message');
            var $chat = $('#chat');

            $messageForm.submit(function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                socket.emit('send message', $messageBox.val());
                $messageBox.val('');
            });

            socket.on('new message', function(data){
                $chat.append(data + "<br/>");
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

My server code

```
var express = require('express'),
    app = express(),
    server = require('http').createServer(app),
    io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

server.listen(3000);

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.sendfile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){
    socket.on('send message', function(data){
        io.sockets.emit('new message', data);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should look into using [`nginx`](http://subprint.com/blog/nginx-load-balancer-and-reverse-proxy-for-node.js-applications-on-digital-ocean) as a reverse proxy. There are many advantages to having `nginx` out front like its ability to serve your static files blazingly fast. Its also battle tested, built for high concurrency, and uses the same event loop based approach to I/O. When you want to scale your app, you can easily setup `nginx` to load balance between a cluster of apps.

If you want to maintain a complete Nodejs stack, you could also take a look at [`node-http-proxy`](https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy) and use it as a reverse proxy/load balancer as well. However, nodejs is not nearly as efficient with static files due to its need to work through userland for file access. `nginx` uses `sendfile(1)` to bypass userland and work directly with the kernel.

### tl;dr

You need a reverse proxy

Comment: well thats really confusing !! +1 though for ur explantion